# How to chat with multiple Apple ID's?

Tags: macos, messages

I have two Apple ID's to have **Messages** chat sessions for work and private separated.
Is it possible to use these both at the same time, on my Mac, at home?

Now, I can only login with one Apple ID at a time.

Anybody else found a workaround?

ps: I know of the alias email addresses, but on work, I don't want to login with my private Apple ID. For obvious reasons.

Comment: So you want to be able to send and receive iMessages from either account? In a similar way that Mail allows that? Does you work account have a phone number tied to it that you want to initiate iMessages from?

Comment: Yes, similar to Mail. But my work account is email-only.

Comment: Have you thought about putting your work Apple ID email account as an alias to your home Apple ID? Let me know if it works. It shouldn't be hard to switch initiation accounts if you can set this up.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't set another Apple ID email as an alias, for iMessage. But this wouldn't solve my problem anyway, because I would still have to sign in at work with my private Apple ID, which is my whole point actually. :)