# How to login to message app with different Apple IDs

Tags: macos, messages, apple-id

I have several Apple IDs, so how can I login with all of these Apple IDs to iMessage on my iMac at once?

I want to send imessage from many apple ID simultaneously. By message app, I sign in my apple ID and I can use imessage.

But, if I try another apple ID, the previous apple ID will be unavailable.

Is it possible to have multiple Apple ID active at the same time?

Comment: Maybe you take the time and explain what your question is and what is the problem you are facing.

Comment: I want to send imessage from many apple ID. By message app, I sign in my apple ID and I can use imessage. But, if I try another apple ID, the previous apple ID will be unavailable.

Comment: I also try to copy message app in order to sign with another apple ID, but it doesn't work well, because it changes both message apps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple Apple ID in Messages.app](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87062/multiple-apple-id-in-messages-app)

Comment: I see that, but that's not the answer for me.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, it appears that you cannot be logged into multiple accounts *at once.* You can use more than one with iMessage, but you will have to switch between them manually every time you want to use a different Apple ID. Here are a couple of questions that may help:

[Multiple Apple ID in Messages.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87062/multiple-apple-id-in-messages-app)

[How to chat with multiple Apple ID's?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80727/how-to-chat-with-multiple-apple-ids?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks MattWillMarron, I will try to do them to see it works or not.

Comment: In step 10, I don't see the new apple ID I just add, so I sign out the previous Apple ID and sign in new apple ID. Therefore, only 1 imessage is available in 1 message app.

Comment: Can I make both apple ID online at the same time ?

Comment: Apparently not, sorry. And sadly, I don't think there are any third-party apps for iMessage accounts.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me in Yosemite. On opening Messages, I still see only the one Apple ID I had previously used to log in to Messages.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work that well. My answer kinda sucked in the first place. I will be removing it if possible.